# How to provide code for tkinter toplevel before data can be accessed

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am trying to have my tkinter toplevel have an access key before the content can be printed.It doesn't output any error but when I provide the access key it doesn't print the content to my terminal.I changed the access key but still I am not able to print the data.

from tkinter import *

```
def qw():
    global en1
    if en1.get() == 2e2c2v:
        print("You have visa to Paris")
        tp.destroy()  # after printing should close the toplevel window
    else:
        print("you dont have access to print the data")


def login_toplevel():
    global en1
    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.geometry("300x300")
    en1 = Entry(tp)
    en1.pack()
    b = Button(tp, text="provide key to print", command=qw)
    b.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

b = Button(root, text= "print", command=login_toplevel).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your access key to string "2e2c2v" then declare global variable for Toplevel window as well `global en1, tp` and parse it for your both functions

```
from tkinter import *


def qw():
    global en1, tp
    if en1.get() == "2e2c2v":
        print("You have visa to Paris")
        tp.destroy()  # after printing should close the toplevel window
    else:
        print("you dont have access to print the data")


def login_toplevel():
    global en1, tp
    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.geometry("300x300")
    en1 = Entry(tp)
    en1.pack()
    b = Button(tp, text="provide key to print", command=qw)
    b.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

b = Button(root, text= "print", command=login_toplevel).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the example you've provided (after I fixed the indentation) I get an "Invalid Syntax" error because you are trying to compare `en1.get()` to a variable `2e2c2v` which you haven't declared.

Update this line . . .

```
if en1.get() == 2e2c2v:
```

. . . To . . .

```
if en1.get() == "2e2c2v":
```

After I did this it worked for me as expected.

Comment: after changing  to "2e2c2v" it print the data but toplevel  tp  doesn't destroy  giving  this error: NameError: name 'tp' is not defined

Comment: Which is a different error. If you have another question, please raise another question and I will happily assist you there.

Answer (score 1):

There's several problem:

- The indentation is not good on your else lines (but I think it's an error of copy/paste)
- `if en1.get() == 2e2c2v:` should be `if en1.get() == "2e2c2v":`
- There is an error when you're entering the right key after the previous correction because tp is not global

Your complete code after correction should be:

```
from tkinter import *


def qw():
    global en1
    global tp
    if en1.get() == "2e2c2v":
        print("You have visa to Paris")
        tp.destroy()  # after printing should close the toplevel window
    else:
        print("you dont have access to print the data")


def login_toplevel():
    global en1
    global tp
    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.geometry("300x300")
    en1 = Entry(tp)
    en1.pack()
    b = Button(tp, text="provide key to print", command=qw)
    b.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

b = Button(root, text= "print", command=login_toplevel).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

EDIT:

And by the way, I think it would be better to use a class instead of using global. It would gives something like that:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("400x400")

        tk.Button(self.root, text= "print", command=self.login_toplevel).pack()

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def qw(self):
        if self.en1.get() == "2e2c2v":
            print("You have visa to Paris")
            self.tp.destroy()  # after printing should close the toplevel window
        else:
            print("you dont have access to print the data")


    def login_toplevel(self):
        self.tp = tk.Toplevel()
        self.tp.geometry("300x300")
        self.en1 = tk.Entry(self.tp)
        self.en1.pack()
        b = tk.Button(self.tp, text="provide key to print", command=self.qw)
        b.pack()

Example().start()
```